# How Can I Increase The Download Speed of Android SDK Manager Using Multi-Threaded Download Managers Like axel or aria2?

Tags: android, aria2

How can I increase the download speed of Android SDK Manager using multi-threaded download managers like axel or aria2?

My idea of the question actually comes from the same idea of Debian GNU/Linux's apt-get and apt-fast. For those who don't know what apt-fast does , it's a script that collects all the download links of all Debian packages to be installed and then sends them all to multi-threaded download managers like axel or aria2 instead of apt-get do the downloading part.. and when everything is downloaded, apt-get takes its roll back in installing the packages.

I noticed that the following command and let me know what will be installed by the Android SDK Manager without actually installing the downloads:

```
android update sdk -u -n
```

I think this command should give a hint on how to grab the download links.

Hopefully my question is clear enough.
Thanks.